# calling a tell and told prolog predicate from java does not work

Tags: java, prolog

I have the below code and when I run it through Prolog it creates a new file with a new rule. For example, I run

```
create_rec(check_symptoms(Symptoms,noOk))
```

it creates a new file with name `rule_new` and content all predicates with the old rules
and the new rule predicate with content is

```
 rule(r15,_G3583,_G3601):-check_symptoms(_G3593,noOk)
```

The problem is that when I call the predicate `create_rec` from Java it does not work:

```
rules([r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14]).

% other predicates

create_rec(Body) :- 
    clause(rules(R_ids), B1),
    last(R_ids,LastRule_id),
    atom_codes(LastRule_id, Rule_codes),
    Rule_codes = [H|T],
    atom_codes(AtomNum,T),
    atom_number(AtomNum,Num),
    NewNum is Num+1,
    atom_codes(NewNum,NewNumCodes),
    atom_codes(NewRule_id,[114|NewNumCodes]),
    append(R_ids, [NewRule_id], New_R_ids),
    retract(rules(R_ids)),
    asserta((rules(New_R_ids))),
    asserta((rule(NewRule_id,A,B) :- Body)),save_rule.  


    save_rule :- 
        tell('rule_new.pl'),
        write(':- dynamic rule/3, rules/1.'),nl,
        write(':- [\'kb_anemia_V5b.pl\'].'),nl,
        write(':- encoding(utf8).'),nl,
        write(':- style_check(-singleton).'),       
        clause(rules(R_ids),B),nl,
        write((rules(R_ids) :- B)),
        write('.'),
        get_rule_data(R_ids),
        told.

get_rule_data([]).
get_rule_data([Rule_id|Rest_Rule_Id]) :-
        clause(rule(Rule_id,A,B),Body1),
        % fix(B,[],B2),
        write(rule(Rule_id,A,B2):-Body1),write('.'), nl,
        get_rule_data(Rest_Rule_Id).


% other predicates
```

The code in Java is:

```
Term consult_arg[] = {
    new Atom(Diagnosis.class.getResource("anemia_diagnosis").getPath())};
Query consult_query = new Query( // to kanei query gia na ginei
                        "consult", //to consult
                        consult_arg);

boolean consulted = consult_query.hasSolution();

if (!consulted) {
    System.err.println("Consult failed");
    System.exit(1); 
}


bodycr = body_txt1.getText();

String t9 = "create_rec(" + bodycr + " )." + "\n";

System.out.println("FUNCTION IS   " + t9);
Query q9 = new Query(t9);
diagnosis = q9.oneSolution().toString();
System.out.println(diagnosis);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "KB is created  ");
```

It takes the body from the textarea and call the predicate. The pop up message is displayed , no bugs were found but the file is not created.

I don't know what is wrong. Can anyone help me?